# How to store iterative sample mean in a data frame?

Tags: r

My sample data has 270 observations which looks like this

```
age id  kilometers
32  1   1
30  2   8
23  3   2
31  4   6
```

I am creating a blank data frame first to store information

```
df <- data.frame(Sample.Num = integer(),
                 Sample.Mean = integer(),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df[1,] <- NA
```

Then I read the file in R

```
sampledata <- read.csv(file.choose(),header = TRUE)
```

Then I am trying to run a for loop which would select two observations randomly from the above 270 rows and store the sample number and sample mean of kilometers. Post that I want to check the sampling distribution of the mean:

```
for (i in 1:100){
  mysample <- sampledata[sample(1:nrow(sampledata),size = 2,replace = TRUE),]
  meansample <- mean(mysample$kilometers,na.rm = TRUE)
  df$Sample.Num <- i
  df$Sample.Mean <- meansample
}
```

But I am very new to R. Every time I run this the sample number changes but the data frame df is storing the last iteration (i.e. 100th iteration). I am unable to store the remaining 99.

Comment: You want `df[i, "Sample.Num"] <- i` and `df[i, "Sample.Mean"] <- meansample` BTW: `meansample` can have the value `16.5` (not an integer).

Comment: Also, you should create `df` with a 100 rows, e.g. `df <- data.frame(Sample.Num = rep(NA, 100), Sample.Mean = rep(NA, 100))`

Comment: Thanks jogo, it worked. Thanks Axeman

Comment: Have a look at `replicate(20, mean(BOD$demand[sample.int(nrow(BOD), size=2, replace=TRUE)], na.rm=TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Sample.Num=1:100, 
  Sample.Mean=replicate(100, mean(sampledata$kilometers[sample.int(nrow(sampledata), size=2, replace=TRUE)], na.rm=TRUE))
)
```

or shorter:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Sample.Num=1:100, 
  Sample.Mean=replicate(100, mean(sample(sampledata$kilometers, size=2, replace=TRUE), na.rm=TRUE))
)
```

If you have no NA in `sampledata$kilometers` then you can do:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Sample.Num=1:100, 
  Sample.Mean=replicate(100, mean(sample(sampledata$kilometers, 2, rep=TRUE)))
)
```

Comment: Thank you jogo, the second solution worked as well and it looks easier. For someone who who wants to avoid loops :-(